# Compact arrangement of DIVs in two directions

Tags: css, html, css-float

It is easy to arrange DIVs horizontally with float. For example:

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
 <div style="float:left; width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color:Yellow;"></div>
 <div style="float:left; width: 150px; height: 60px; background-color:Blue;"></div>
 <div style="float:left; width: 140px; height: 240px; background-color:Green;"></div>
 <div style="float:left; width: 180px; height: 200px; background-color:Red;"></div>
 <div style="float:left; width: 130px; height: 160px; background-color:Purple;"></div>
</div>
```

This will produce:
[image]

But how to arrange the DIVs both horizontally and vertically? In this case, how to shift the Red and Purple DIVs upper where there is empty space (under Yellow and Blue DIVs)?

**NOTE:** This is just an example, and I wish to find a method to make the arrangement for any set of DIVs (not only this typical example).

Comment: whats the actual layout u want? will be better if u can share some image of the actual layout(required).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are working with a dynamic set of arbitrarily sized objects, there is no pure CSS method to achieve this. You can get close by using a CSS3 multi-column layout if:

1. You only need to support modern browsers.
2. All objects can be arranged into equal-height groups.

Here, objects are arranged in groups of 300px height.

```
<div id="blocks">
  <div style="height: 100px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
  <div style="height: 200px; background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div style="height: 300px; background-color: green;"></div>
  <div style="height: 200px; background-color: red;"></div>
  <div style="height: 160px; background-color: purple;"></div>
</div>

#blocks {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 0;
  width: 450px;
}
#blocks div {
  width: 150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RTLun/

Comment: This is a brilliant idea and I really like it, but the problem is the necessity for a fixed height, as we cannot control it for a dynamic set of DIVs.

Comment: If you only care about webkit browsers, you can use "column-break-inside: avoid" to force each new item to a new column. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/RTLun/2/ for an example.

Comment: Absolutely marvelous! It is really remarkable, and I believe that the future of web designing is based on CSS3. All major browsers are attempting to support it.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `position:absolute` css property along with `top`,`left` to achieve the same.

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
 <div style="position:absolute; width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color:Yellow;"></div>
 <div style="position:absolute; left:200px; width: 150px; height: 60px; background-color:Blue;"></div>
 <div style="position:absolute;left:350px; width: 140px; height: 240px; background-color:Green;"></div>
 <div style="position:absolute;top:100px; width: 180px; height: 200px; background-color:Red;"></div>
 <div style="position:absolute; left:200px;top:60px;width: 130px; height: 160px; background-color:Purple;"></div>
</div>
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sa63b/)**

Answer (score 2):

For arrange divs vertically you may use jquery plugin [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

It has effect like this: 
 [image: work of jquery.masonry]

This plugin is very easy to use:

```
    $(function(){
      $('#container').masonry({
        // options
        itemSelector : '.item',
      });
    });
```

and this [***live demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/4gUuC/1/) showed how it work in your example

Comment: As a matter of fact, I got the whole idea from mansory, but I prefer to make a simple arrangement with CSS rather than javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you are no big fan of absolute positioning (like I am) try this:

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
    <div style="float: left;">
        <div id="yellow"></div>
        <div id="red"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <div id="blue"></div>
        <div id="purple"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

With the corresponding CSS:

```
#red {
    width: 180px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: Red;
}

#yellow {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: Yellow;
}

#blue {
    width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: Blue;
}

#green {
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    height: 240px;
    background-color: Green;
}

#purple {
    width: 130px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: Purple;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vMeU9/1/)'s a small demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without manipulating the markup like this:

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
 <div style="float:left; width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color:Yellow;"></div>
 <div style="float:left; width: 150px; height: 60px; background-color:Blue;"></div>
 <div style="float:right; width: 140px; height: 240px; background-color:Green;margin-right:10px"></div>
 <div style="float:left; width: 180px; height: 200px; background-color:Red;"></div>
 <div style="float:left; width: 130px; height: 160px; background-color:Purple;margin-top:-40px;margin-left:20px"></div>
</div>
```

Check the fiddle

### http://jsfiddle.net/E6VkW/