# How to basically re-arrange DIVs as jQuery masonry does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, html

Masonry is an advanced jQuery plugin with various options. Since my knowledge in jQuery is limited, I cannot understand how it works by reading the masonry code. What is the basic jQuery API behind a plugin like this for re-arrangement of DIVs? I mean how we can basically and simply re-arrange DIVs with the aid of jQuery?

**NOTE:** As discussed in the comments, Masonry was an example for the behavior I am referring to. I want to know how jQuery can basically re-arrange the position of DIVs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so let's say you have 3 divs and you just want them arranged on load. Let's say by height. Let's also say for this example that you don't care to animate them, you just want them arranged by height.

Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hMmLd/1/

using jquery I sort the elements by height then re-draw them in their new order on the screen.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. I tried something similar, but the problem is when the DIVs goes to the next line and create a new row. You can see the problem in your example: http://jsfiddle.net/etrader/hMmLd/3/

Comment: Right, and that's because of the float parameter in the css. Since my example is only showing how js rearranges elements, it is not helping to solve that problem, which is a much more involved one. jQuery masonry or jQuery isotope are pretty complex, so describing their actions here is futile since it is much better to simply suggest you use one of them. You can mimic it if you want but it is a serious effort in absolute positioning, top and left margins - or moz-transform. Way too involved to explain here or in a fiddle.

Comment: Exactly, I was searching for an alternative in CSS (instead of float). You are quite right, changing the CSS to absolute positions by jQuery is a complicated process, and I hope to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

I am learning how to do the same thing Ali. If you provide an example of specifically what you want to re-arrange, I can post a better answer. In the meantime, this link has been invaluable:

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Also, I found that searching google with the terms 'JQuery DOM manipulation' provided lots of good information and some great tutorials.

Comment: Thanks Rick! Very nice hint to start searching. I just want to shift boxes upward to fill vertical gap. First I tried to do so with CSS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222859/compact-arrangement-of-divs-in-two-directions