# Masonry layout using MDL

Tags: material-design-lite

I am trying to create dynamic tiles using the `mdl-grid` and `mdl-cell` , but the cell is stretching to the maximum height of the column in that row .

To see the difference Here is the example from Angular material design . Here the tiles are displayed dynamically and the columns are not taking the max width of other columns in that row .

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpbxzz

Here is the second example using material lite , But here you can see the columns are stretching

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVKaod

Is there any way I can create dynamic tiles using MDL ?

**UPDATE**

After researching for few hours I found this approach is called **Masonry layout** . I searched for it and found the below ones . But I can not able to do it with flex layout .

1) JQuery Plugin https://github.com/desandro/masonry

2) This is with CSS3
http://web.archive.org/web/20111226183221/http://sickdesigner.com/index.php/2011/html-css/masonry-css-getting-awesome-with-css3

here is another link
http://jsfiddle.net/RTLun/

here stackoverflow  link

[Compact arrangement of DIVs in two directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222859/compact-arrangement-of-divs-in-two-directions/8223454#8223454)

**UPDATE**

I found the above links doesn't maintain the order of the items , But this one does . But can not find CSS code to do this

http://michieldewit.github.io/isotope-modulo-columns/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using http://masonry.desandro.com/ , it perfectly works for me.

```
<div class="mdl-grid masonry-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col-desktop masonry-grid-item">
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col-desktop masonry-grid-item">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry- layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var elem = document.querySelector('.masonry-grid');
    var msnry = new Masonry( elem, {
    // options
    itemSelector: '.masonry-grid-item'
    });
</script>
```